# ElmahR doesnt load properly on IIS

Tags: iis, deployment, iis-7.5, elmah

I've been fiddeling around with ElmahR for the last two days and was planning to push it to our dev-playground for testing.
However, it doesnt load properly when running on IIS 7.5

I've fired up the deployed solution on 3 different machines with IIS Express without problems.
On IIS 7.5 it gets stuck at "Loading..." or "Sending Command", depending if it is set up as a sub application under default website or as a standalone webapplication.

The used system is Windows Server 2008 r2 sp1, IIS 7.5 .NET 4 application pool integrated mode. (all 3 machines)

I can't find the problem at hand; hope you can help.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer yet, it should be a comment but I cannot comment here :) I'm the author of ElmahR, I was not aware of the issue, last time I tested it on IIS 7.5 was a while ago and I did not have any problem, I'll have to recheck. Right now I'm not at home but I'll have a look at it when back, possibly before next weekend. And thanks for using it :)

**UPDATE**: I think I solved the problem, I blogged about it [here](http://www.robychechi.it/roby/tech-blog/elmahr-0.9.1-is-out). Basically, there were a couple of javascript bugs:

- in one point I was not correctly setting the root of the application
- under IE7/8 a better check about the `plugins` object was needed (the same code was running fine on IE9/Chrome/Firefox/Safari...)

The online [repo](https://bitbucket.org/wasp/elmahr/wiki/Home) is up to date, and [the sample setup zipped file](https://bitbucket.org/wasp/elmahr/downloads/ElmahRSampleSetup.0.9.1.zip) too.

Comment: If you have some time to spare and time to read; I'll provide you with some detailed information on the problem and how I "solved" it.

Comment: Sure, it would be great :) I had some thoughts about it, you could have such a behavior if you have problems with the errors database, but so far it's just a guess. And I'm already working on ElmahR to make it more robust (http://www.robychechi.it/roby/tech-blog/making-elmahr-more-rock-solid)

Comment: I've been able to reproduce your problem, which is cause by a mix of factors: a bug in ElmahR (fixed) when you were trying under default website, and a weird javascript behavior on IE7/8 (I guess you were trying with one of those IE versions on your 2008 server) when using an empty object (fixed). Both problems are related to quite recent additions which I did not test deep enough. By the end of the day I should update the online repo and the zipped samples, I'll add a detailed answer when done.

Comment: That covers it almost completly. The workaround I used, was to not use the Default WebSite (which runs on TCP:81) but to create a Website solemly for Elmahr running on Port 83 (82 wouldnt work either).

Dont get confused by port 83. I've choosen tis one, because it is not accessible from the outside, plus 80 and 81 were out of the question at this time.

Anyway: Thank you for your support on that matter Wasp.